# Add <map> after each <img> tag using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I wrote the code below to add "map" after each "image" tag where "img" has a usemap defined
But it dosent seem to be working. I checked "result" is not empty Here ASP.net ABCService is a web service.

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {
$("img").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).attr("usemap") != "") {
        var name = $(this).attr("usemap");
        name = name.substring(1, name.length);
        var map;
        ABCService.GetMap(name, function (result, eventArgs) {
           alert(result);
           $(this).after(result);
        });

    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` doesn't mean what you think it means inside the function you're giving to `ABCService.GetMap()`.

Try this:

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {

    $("img").each(function (i) {
        $img = $(this)
        if ($img.attr("usemap")) {
            var name = $(this).attr("usemap").substring(1);
            ABCService.GetMap(name, function (result, eventArgs) {
               alert(result);
               $img.after(result);
            });

        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** If you only want the `<map>` to appear after `<img>` tags with the attribute `usemap` then do this...

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {
    $("img[usemap]").each(function (i) {
        $img = $(this)
        var name = $(this).attr("usemap").substring(1);
        ABCService.GetMap(name, function (result, eventArgs) {
           alert(result);
           $img.after(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks This works but there is one problem it adds map to end of all images eg <img/><img/><img/> <map/><map/><map/>

Comment: That's because that's what the code does! It adds whatever `result` is to be directly after all `img` tags on the page.

Comment: Ok, But i want it <map> to appear after each <img> tag not after all <img> tags. How can that be done.. Thanks!

Comment: Uhhhh... that statement didn't exactly make sence, but I think I understand what you mean: See my edit.

Comment: I am sorry if i was not clear. Your code works but i want <img/><map/><img/></map> ie the tags should be alternate. currently it adds all the map tags together after all the img tags